# Why can't I send my props to a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a file that is using React Router to hold all of my routes. I also have a dashboard component where I am doing a GET request to get a list of all the restaurant reservations in my database. I am trying to create another component called SeatReservation where I can click on the listed reservation and assign it an id, so it will appear occupied.

Routes.js

```
function Routes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact={true} path='/'>
        <Redirect to={'/dashboard'} />
      </Route>
      <Route exact={true} path='/reservations'>
        <Redirect to={'/dashboard'} />
      </Route>
      <Route path='/dashboard'>
        <Dashboard date={today()} />
      </Route>
      <Route path='/reservations/new'>
        <ReservationForm />
      </Route>
      <Route path='/tables/new'>
        <TablesForm />
      </Route>
      <Route path='/reservations/:reservationId/seat'>
        <SeatReservation />
      </Route>
      <Route>
        <NotFound />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

This of course will bring me to the correct URL and a new page.

Dashboard.js

```
function Dashboard({ date }) {
  const [reservations, setReservations] = useState([]);
  const [reservationsError, setReservationsError] = useState(null);
  const [table, setTable] = useState([]);
  let location = useLocation();

  // Grab the query string to check what day is is
  const params = useQuery();
  const queryDate = params.get('date');

  // Format today's date so we can compare it to query string
  let today = new Date();
  let day = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  let month = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  let year = today.getFullYear();
  today = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;

  useEffect(loadDashboard, [date]);

  function loadDashboard() {
    const abortController = new AbortController();
    setReservationsError(null);
    listReservations({ date }, abortController.signal)
      .then(setReservations)
      .catch(setReservationsError);
    return () => abortController.abort();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAllTables = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/tables');

      const tablesFromAPI = await response.json();
      setTable(tablesFromAPI);
    };
    getAllTables();
  }, []);

  return (
    <main className='container' style={{ maxWidth: '600px' }}>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      <div>
        {/* <h4 className='mb-0'>Reservations for date: {date}</h4> */}

        {queryDate === today || queryDate === null ? (
          <DashboardList
            reservations={reservations}
            setReservations={setReservations}
            date={date}
          />
        ) : (
          <DashboardRes
            date={date}
            reservations={reservations}
            setReservations={setReservations}
            reservationsError={reservationsError}
            setReservationsError={setReservationsError}
          />
        )}
        <Seat table={table} setTable={setTable} />
        {location.pathname ===
          `/reservations/${reservations.reservation_id}/seat` && (
          <SeatReservation table={table} setTable={setTable} />
        )}
      </div>
      <ErrorAlert error={reservationsError} />
      {/* {JSON.stringify(reservations)} */}
    </main>
  );
}
```

I set up a conditional to check if it was on the home route or not (in this case it's looking for /reservations/:reservationId/seat) so that the component doesn't automatically show up.

However, no matter what I do, whenever I pass props to `<SeatReservation />`, it say's it's undefined.

Am I not able to use the `<SeatReservation />` twice, or am I passing it props incorrectly?

Comment: One thing's for sure: you can use the component twice! So there is something wrong with how the props are passed. Unfortunately you can't tell what from your code. Where do the values of table and setTable come from? Looks like they aren't in scope.

Comment: @seesharper Well it's good to know I can use them more than once! I just updated the post with the entire Dashboard component. When I console log table in Dashboard, I can see my values. It's not until I pass them down as props that they become undefined.

Comment: The `Dashboard` component is rendered only on `path='/dashboard'`, so it will ***never*** be mounted and rendered when the path is on `path='/reservations/:reservationId/seat'`. You can, without a doubt reuse components. What isn't clear to me is which one you think you are rendering and which you think you are passing props to. The `SeatReservation` rendered by your router (*and thus is the accessible one*) isn't passed any props. Are you trying to pass some route state to the other route rendering `SeatReservation`, or are you needing to lift `table` state up so it's accessible by both?

Comment: @DrewReese The goal is to have `SeatReservation` rendered by the Dashboard because that's where the `table` state is among several other props I need to send; all GET requests to my API. If I take `SeatReservation` out of the router, how can I have it rendered in my Dashboard instead of having to lift up the state?

Comment: Sounds like a case for some good old-fashioned conditional rendering when you have `table` state available. What are any other conditions for displaying that `SeatReservation` component?

Comment: @DrewReese So on the dashboard I have the list of restaurant reservations. Each reservation has a button, and when clicked it takes me to the SeatReservation path. Which is essentially the only condition that will show the SeatReservation component

Comment: "SeatReservation path", is that the `path='/reservations/:reservationId/seat'` route? If this is the component you are trying to render and you don't want to centralize your `table` state then an alternative could be to send the specific reservation data in route state for the route transition. Can you update your question to show us how you display the reservations and link to the other page rendering `SeatReservation` and that entire component?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for the location API you can use useLocation from the **react-router** context API:

```js
import {
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";

...

let location = useLocation();
return (
    <main className='container' style={{ maxWidth: '600px' }}>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      <div>

      ...

      {location.pathname ===
          `/reservations/${reservations.reservation_id}/seat` && (
          <SeatReservation table={table} setTable={setTable} />
        )}
```

Comment: Yeah I have that set up, but this issue is that when I try to send the component any props from <Dashboard />, they are undefined. The previous components receive the props no problem, but they weren't first used in the Routes.js file. So I'm wondering if I have to send props differently or can't use the component twice

Comment: If you have undefined props. This means you call your component somewhere else in your code without props.